# if and else statement python

Tags: python, if-statement, search, python-re

```py
import re
social = '1234'
phone = '5678'

user = int(input("Please tell me your last four digit of your social: "))

user1 = int(input("your last digit of your phone number: "))

info_checker = re.search("^12.*34$", social)

info_checker1 = re.search("^56.*78$", phone)

if info_checker and info_checker1:
    print("Great you're all set")
else:
    print("Sorry we couldn't find this info")
```

Whenever I put the user's data even if it's right or wrong it prints out the if statement only?

Comment: first use `print(info_checker, info_checker1)` to see  what you get. OR learn how to use debuger.

Comment: you have to use `user` and `user1` in `search()` but you use `social` and `phone` which have always the same value `'1234'`, `'5678'`

Comment: user, user1 assigned to input statement! When I do that it prints out TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object –

Comment: dont' convert to `input()` to `int()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use correct variables in `search()` - `user` instead of `social` and `user1` instead of `phone`

```
info_checker = re.search("^12.*34$", user)

info_checker1 = re.search("^56.*78$", user1)
```

---

**EDIT:** And don't convert user's strings to integers.

---

```
import re

user  = input("Please tell me your last four digit of your social: ")
user1 = input("your last digit of your phone number: ")

info_checker  = re.search("^12.*34$", user)
info_checker1 = re.search("^56.*78$", user1)

if info_checker and info_checker1:
    print("Great you're all set")
else:
    print("Sorry we couldn't find this info")
```

Comment: When I do that it prints out TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: don't use `int()` in `int(input(...))` and keep it as string.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much:)